# laravel livewire get groupBy name list

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-10

I'm trying to get groupBy value and it giving successfully, after this I'm need only group list array
how to archive that.

**my Code**

```
$this->StudentList = Student::get();
$data =  $this->StudentList->sortBy('date', SORT_NATURAL)->groupby('date');
                 
($data);
```

**GroupBy Result**

```
array:14 [▼   
  "2024-01-01" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1977 ▶}
  "2024-01-02" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1978 ▶}
  "2024-01-03" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1979 ▶}
  "2024-01-04" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1980 ▶}
  "2024-01-05" => Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1981 ▶}
]
```

**need this group date like this in array**

```
array:14 [▼   
  "2024-01-01"  
  "2024-01-02"  
  "2024-01-03"  
  "2024-01-04" 
  "2024-01-05"  
]
```

laravel get groupBy name list

Comment: Post the full code.  You can use `array_keys($data->toArray());` with current dataset if needed

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam posted full code check once

Comment: @Abdulla Nilam array_keys($data->toArray()); worked thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use to get the keys

```
$dateList = $data->keys()->all();
```

or

```
$dateList = array_keys($data->toArray());
```